# Java - Looping And GUI

Tags: java

:)

I want to make something like this -
I have for example four labels:

```
lblError1;
lblError2;
lblError3;
lblError4;
```

All they are `set.Visible(false);`

Now I want loop that will set those labels to visible. If k=2 then first two labels sets to visible. If k=4 the first four labels sets to visible.

My idea:

```
int k=2;
for (i=1; i<k+1; i++) {
  (lbl.Error + i).setVisible(true);
}
```

This doesn't work. There is one rule: I have to make it with loop. If there is another great way, how to do it in a EFFICIENT way without loop, please tell me. Otherwise tell me, how to make loop that will work for this solution.

Thank You very much! :))

Comment: You should read up on arrays.

Comment: You can't use string concatenation for variable names in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not have an array of labels and use the `for` loop to set their visibility based on the value of `k`. It'd be more readable than your `(lbl.Error + i)` (which I doubt if it'll work).

```
for (int i=0; i<k; i++) {
  labels[i].setVisible(true); // where labels is the array of label.
}
```

**Edit:-**

Say if you're using `JLabel`, then you can create an array of labels like this:-

```
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[yourArraySize];
for (int i=0; i<labels.length; i++) {
  labels[i] = new JLabel(); // You can also use JLabel(labelText) constructor.
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. The loop and Your solution look good and it would work, but can You show me please, how to make array like that?